# Download a webpage into server using PHP like Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, download

I am writing a script in PHP. I want to be able to download a complete webpage locally along with all of its requirements such as css/js/images into the server in such a way that it is no longer dependent on the orignal page. It means the links in the page be replaced with local links. Exactly the same way how Google Chrome downloads the webpage in local computer. Is there any library or prebuilt tool to do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you generate your pages or just statically type all resources?

Answer (score 0):

Make your pages dynamically generated. Structure:

```
\web
 | - index.html
 | - about.html
 \ images
 \ css
 \ js
```

Keep every resource below `*.html` so that viewing in `file://` you will not receive `Cross-Origin` exception (because having `css` in one folder and `index.html` in another folder under same root will not work).

---

When I did this, all my resources had dynamic links like `($isOffline ? '/css/' : '../../css/').'style.css'` and all content was generated using Cron Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You should deploye your project to a local server (Wamp) or debian with your requirements.

And after you can use your project with local links such as images, css or js files.